# how to query a multiple column in django

Tags: python, sql, django

I have a problem in displaying specific columns in my model in django...
I have read in the documentation in about the queryset feature of django.
my question is that it is also possible in django to run just like this query?

```
select name, age, address from person;
```

can anyone can give me an idea, i also try it like this

```
Mymodel.objects.get(name, age, address)
```

but there are error in the parameter of name, age and address...

thanks...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there are a few different ways. django normally wraps the data in model instances, which is part of the point of the orm. you deal with objects and django deals with the database. so

```
for person in MyMydel.objects.all():
    do_something_with(person.name)
```

having said that, if you only want certain attributes, e.g. for performance, you can use [values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values)

```
MyMode.objects.values('name', 'age', 'address')
```

which returns a list of dicts with those values

Answer (score 10):

If you want only some columns use [`only`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.only):

```
Mymodel.objects.only('name', 'age', 'address')
```

If you *don't want* some columns use [`defer`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#defer):

```
Mymodel.objects.defer('some_big_field')
```

You can still access field you haven't queried, but it will cost you one mode DB hit.

Also you can use [`values`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values) and [`values_list`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) methods, but instead of model instances they return list of dicts and list of lists respectively.

Comment: +1 nice summary of different approaches, also if one needs complete control over the SQL statement one could use [`raw`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#django.db.models.Manager.raw) method on the model manager.